# Как в стандартном элементе управления ymaps.control.SearchControl изменить placeholder

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Хочу изменить стандартный placeholder "Адрес или объект" на свой.
создаю

```
const mySearchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
options: {
provider: new CustomSearchProvider(objectManager),
noPlacemark: true,
resultsPerPage: 5,           
}
});
mapOrder.controls.add(mySearchControl, { float: 'right' });
```

Как добавить свой placeholder

Answer (score 1):

У контрола [searchControl](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/) есть стандартный метод изменения плейсхолдера [placeholderContent](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/#control.SearchControl__param-parameters.options.placeholderContent), изменяемый в опциях, также как и noPlacemark в вашем примере:

```
placeholderContent: 'Что-нибудь найдём',
```